# From dictionary to organized Excel

Tags: pandas, dictionary, export-to-excel

Good Morning,

I have a dictionary: organized this way below; And What I want to do is use the dictionary values as the column number for the Key. As showed below:

My first idea was to loop through the dictionary and create a text file where dico_values = tabs and then transform this new file into an excel file but this seems one too much step. Cheers to all

[image: Raw Dico]

[image]

Comment: Hi! Please do not share images of your data. Share things that the community can use to try to solve the problem.

Comment: This is public data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could perhaps try this:

```py
new_dico = {value: [] for value in dico.values()}  # {1: [], 2: [], 3: [], ...}
for key, value in dico.items():
    new_dico[value].append(key)
    for otherkey in new_dico.keys():
        if otherkey == value:
            continue
        else:
            new_dico[otherkey].append("")

# new_dico == {1: ["President of ...", "Members of ..", "", ...], 2: ["", "", "President's Office", ...], ...}

# Then you can make a dataframe of 'new_dico' with pandas, for instance
```

Comment: This can work, but I would be loosing information, in the sense that I need that order. I really want the blanks seen in the excel because I hope to fill them later using pandas method;

Comment: Following your comment, I modified my answer: a second loop adds an empty string where blanks are expected.